# advantages of java's ConcurrentHashMap for a get-only map?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

Consider these two situations:

1. a map which you are going to populate once at the beginning and then will be accessed from many different threads.
2. a map which you are going to use as cache that will be accessed from many different threads. you would like to avoid computing the result that will be stored in the map unless it is missing, the get-computation-store block will be synchronized. (and the map will not otherwise be used)

In either of these cases, does `ConcurrentHashMap` offer you anything additional in terms of thread safety above an ordinary `HashMap`?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, it should not matter in practice, but there is no guarantee that modifications written to a regular hashmap will ever be seen by other threads.  So if one thread initially creates and populates the map, and that thread never synchronized with your other threads, then those threads may never see the initial values set into the map.

The above situation is unlikely in practice, and would only take a single synchronization event or happens before guarantee between the threads (read / write to a volatile variable for instance) to ensure even theoretical correctness.

In the second case, there is a concern since access to a HashMap that modifies it structurally (adding a value) requires synchronization.  Furthermore, you need some type of synchronization to establish a happens-before relationship / shared visibility with the other threads or there is no guarantee that the other threads will see the new values you put in.  ConcurrentHashMap offers these guarantees and will not break when one thread modifies it structurally.

Comment: To comment on my own post, for your situation you may get the best performance using a copy on write map implementation (for which I believe Apache has an implementation).  For many reads and very few writes, it should out perform ConcurrentHashMap (but I have not tested this).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in thread *safety*, no.  For scenario #2 there is a difference in performance and a small difference in timing guarantees.

There will be no synchronization for your scenario #2, so threads that want to use the cache don't have to queue up and wait for others to finish.  However, in order to get that benefit you don't have hard happens-before relationships at the synchronization boundaries, so it's possible two threads will compute the same cached value more or less at the same time.  This is generally harmless as long as the computation is repeatable.

(There is also the slight difference that ConcurrentHashMap does not allow `null` to be used as a key.)